# What nested class type is best suitable for Domain Events?

Tags: java, domain-driven-design, inner-classes, clean-architecture, hexagonal-architecture

I am following Domain Driven Design and Clean/ Hexagonal architecture in my Java microservice. I have domain events declared in my aggregate root class as non-static nested classes. My question is whether these classes should be static nested classes or non-static nested classes(inner classes)?

I used non-static nested classes but IntelliJ IDEA suggests to make them static. According to the Hardcore Java book by Robert Simmons,

> an inner class is instance-scoped and a static nested class is class-scoped.

As I understood in the Domain Driven Design, without an aggregate instance, it doesn't make any sense to have domain events instances. This is the reason why I chose to go with non-static nested classes. Can someone explain this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The main difference between nested classes types**

- *non-static* nested class has full access to the members and methods of the class within which it is nested. It has reference to the outer class instance.

- *static* nested class does not have a reference to a nesting instance, so a static nested class cannot invoke non-static methods or access non-static fields of an instance of the class within which it is nested.

So if we will define `Domain Event` as a non-static nested class it will have full access to the instance of `Aggregate`. This violates the main `Domain Event` characteristics.

**Immutability**

`Domain Event` must be immutable,  attaching the whole `Aggregate` state violates immutability. It should not have the whole state of the concept, only the copy of contextual information that might be useful for someone who subscribes to this event.

**Domain Event doesn't have business logic**

Besides `Aggregate` can encapsulate business constraints. If `Domain Event` has an instance of aggregate, it has access to the business logic.

**As result,** we need to use only *static* nested class.

Please note `Domain Events` may be consumed by the local, and foreign, Bounded Contexts, but `Aggregate` is limited by one context. In this case, better move `Domain Events` to a separate class. There may be exclusions
[Bounded contexts sharing a same aggregate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29728001/bounded-contexts-sharing-a-same-aggregate)

Comment: This is an excellent explanation. Thanks. About moving Domain Events to a separate file, only Aggregate must be able to create domain events right? How can we impose such a restriction if we move them out? Right now, I have them as nested classes with private constructors.

Answer (score 1):

A static nested class seems a better choice to me because there's not really a reason for the domain events to have a reference to the `this` of your aggregate root (which is what they'd get if they were nested classes).  It's better to be explicit that the domain events have a field explicitly identifying what they are events for (which doesn't necessarily have to be an aggregate).